# Парсинг сайта curl php

Tags: php, парсер, curl

Здравствуйте, как можно спарсить информацию с этого сайта (авторизованным) cp.wowcircle.com (login: afasfafs , pass: afasfafs для теста) с помощью php и возможно ли вообще?

```
<?php

// САЙТ
$url = 'http://cp.wowcircle.com/direct.php';
// НАЧАЛО
$ch = curl_init($url);

// ПОДГОТОВКА ЗАГОЛОВКОВ
$uagent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36";
// ВСЯКИЕ ПАРАМЕТРЫ
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $uagent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

// ДОБАВЛЯЕМ КУКИ В ПАРАМЕТРЫ
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "PMBC=96152e8e9a0168a731539c5e52c6b39a; PHPSESSID=jl0i13pn3157qca807jgp0jqa7; ServerName=WoW+Circle+3.3.5a+x5; serverId=1");

$html = curl_exec($ch);
// КОНЕЦ
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($html);
```

Код работает, но есть проблема, как передать запрос такого вот вида:
Request Payload:

```
{"action":"wow_Services","method":"cmdLogin","data":[{"accountName":"dsa","password":"dadad","captcha":"ADASDAD"}],"type":"rpc","tid":3}
```

И возможно как-то спарсить капчу с http://cp.wowcircle.com/ и подставить ее в этот же запрос?

Comment: Робот не может врать, поэтому он не может пройти эту каптчу:)

А в целом - все, что Вы можете сделать в браузере, все можно сделать и кодом.

Answer (score 1):

Запрос можно передать дополнив строками:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
```

С капчей ничего не посоветую.

Comment: Можете помочь написать сам запрос, я просто не совсем понимаю вложенность json?

Comment: `$payload = '{"action":"wow_Services","method":"cmdLogin","data":[{"accountName":"dsa","password":"dadad","captcha":"ADASDAD"}],"type":"rpc","tid":3}';`

Comment: Добавил, результат не изменился, не ошибок, ничего

Comment: Попробуйте дополнить: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));` и изменить `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` на` true`